# Razor Pages cannot find partialView even it exist in the same directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to call a partial view named "topbar", but every time i try to call it with extension (`<partial name="topbar.cshtml" />`) or without it :  `<partial name="topbar" />`
it also give me error that cannot find the partial view.

Error : [image]

While my folder structure got the file in the place it searched for, so I don't know what to do.

Folders Photo : [image]

Comment: try to set full address
"~/Areas/Admin/Pages/Shared/topbar.cshtml"

Comment: I've tried that too, gives the same error

Comment: since the correct location was searched, maybe the problem is something inside the file? no idea what that might be, though. did you rebuild your project? could there be any invisible characters in the filename messing things up?!

Comment: Could you please share your `topbar.cshtml` partial view details as well?

Comment: Hello, have you tried the solution provided? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

> Razor Pages cannot find partialView even it exist in the same
> directory. While my folder structure got the file in the place it
> searched for, so I don't know what to do.

Well, based on your scenario and shared code snippet it seems that, you might have two major reason for your exception.

First reason might be your `_ViewStart.cshtml` page doesn't have the correct references or the layout path is incorrect.

So I have the following folder structure and the correct `_ViewStart.cshtml` should be as following:

[image]

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
   
    switch (ViewData["Title"])
    {
        case "admin":
            Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Pages/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
            break;
        default:
            Layout = "_Layout";
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** For the demo, I am checking `ViewData["Title"]` the user is admin or normal user and then deciding the admin layout. Make sure your path is correct.This can also cuase the exception which you are getting.

Another reason could be the Asynchronous HTML Helper issue, as you may know its always recommended to use async with awaited call as an IHtmlContent type wrapped in a Task so we should better use PartialAsync.

Therefore, you should call your `topbar.cshtml` partial view as following:

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Areas/Admin/Pages/Shared/topbar.cshtml")
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asynchronous-html-helper) if you want to study more.